# React component with no data : condition in ParentComponent or return null in ChildComponent?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding the best pattern (performance, lisibility, etc.) to use when there is no data to display inside a React component. Could you tell me what you think is the best option and why ?

**OPTION 1**

Check if there's data inside `ParentComponent` before calling `ChildComponent` (with `data` props).

```
// Parent component

{data.length > 0 && (
    <ChildComponent data={data} />
)}
```

**OPTION 2**

No check inside `ParenComponent`, but return `null` inside `ChildComponent` if there's no data.

```
// Child component

if (!data.length) {
    return null;
}

return (
    <h1>List</h1>
    <ul>{data.map((item) => <li>{item.name}</li>)}</ul>
)
```

Comment: Why call a component when you don't need to?

Comment: @SeanLawton I agree but I've been asked by my superior to change option 1 by option 2 so I was wondering if there's a reason I'm not aware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say 1 option will be more performant, because in that case we don't create a Node inside React VDOM tree - we create it only when it's needed. In the second case we create a node (function call `createElement` under the hood of React), and then render nothing.

But there are not very much difference in the performance between these 2 approaches to be honest: probably we can win more in the code readability and declarativeness in the 2 option (of course if you don't have some heavy calculations before return)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Alex. There's a bit of logic in the `ChildComponent` before the return but nothing too heavy (retrieving some other data from Redux state).

Comment: In that particular case I'd definitely go with the 1st option: even because you should complete all `useSelector`, `useState` hooks (which are again function calls) before return (remember conditions rule of hooks usage https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level), which might add more complexity to the code.